# How to encode messages with “map” using google-protobuf in JavaScript? (protocol buffers)

Tags: javascript, protocol-buffers, grpc-node

I wanna ask that how to encode (serialization) Map Fields.

According to the google guide, "JavaScript Generated Code" contains the following function for Map Fields. The decoding function (`getFooMap()`) is generated. But I couldn't find the encoding functions or guide for map type anywhere. (I thought there would be a function like `setXXXMap()`, but I couldn't find it.)

How should I encode Map Fields?

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/javascript-generated#map

Map Fields

For this message with a map field:

```
message Bar {}

message Baz {
  map<string, Bar> foo = 1;
}
```

the compiler generates the following instance method:

`getFooMap()`: Returns the Map containing foo's key-value pairs. You can then use Map methods to interact with the map.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an exmaple:

**map-test.proto**

```
syntax = "proto3";

package test;

message Table {
    string label = 1;
    map<string, int32> data = 2;
}
```

Generate protobuf:

```
$ protoc --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:. ./map-test.proto
```

**map-test.js**

```
var proto = require('./map-test_pb');

// Serialization

var msg = new proto.Table();
msg.setLabel("Test");
msg.getDataMap().set("a", 1);
msg.getDataMap().set("b", 2);
msg.getDataMap().set("c", 3);

var serialized = msg.serializeBinary();

// Deserialization

var deserialized = proto.Table.deserializeBinary(serialized);
console.log(deserialized.getLabel());

deserialized.getDataMap().forEach(function(v, k) {
    console.log(k, v);
});

// console.log(deserialized.getDataMap().entries());
// console.log(deserialized.getDataMap().get("a"));
```

**Output:**

```
Test
a 1
b 2
c 3
```

You can use `set()` and `get()` methods of the map to store and retrieve values; `forEach()` to iterate through all the KV pairs, etc. Check [these map tests](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/2b7430d96aeff2bb624c8d52182ff5e4b9f7f18a/js/maps_test.js#L87) for more examples.